# Image view in collection view must center and aspect fit swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I am try in imageView in collection view in center and aspect fit, but not do any things in collection view. please any one help me

```
imageproduct.center = self.viewImage.center
imageproduct.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.viewImage.addSubview(imageproduct)
```

Comment: Try adding constraints to imageproduct

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it centerX and centerY constraints after adding into subviews?

```
imageproduct.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageproduct.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageproduct.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewImage.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Also make sure your self.viewImage is also given proper constraint.

Comment: you'll also need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for any view using autolayout constraints in code

Comment: I am try add in UICollectionViewCell but not do any things

Comment: share some more code where you're adding to `UICollectionViewCell` @ShahedAboSaleem

Comment: In function set data put this code and get in view controller